# How to highlight buttons when pressed , like the ios13 calculator in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calculator

I created a button in a swift project, now I want to make my button to glow when it pressed like what happen in apple's calculator in ios13, I used  `button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true` but it's not what I want.

Comment: One of the possible approach is to override isHighlighted property and change alpha on its didSet depends on current value

Answer (score 0):

You can either set [adjustsImageWhenHighlighted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624031-adjustsimagewhenhighlighted) to `true`:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
```

or if that isn't good enough you can add another image for the `.highlighted` state via [setBackgroundImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624016-setbackgroundimage):

```
button.setBackgroundImage(lighBackgroundImage, for: .highlighted)
```

You can do this in the interface builder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must override isSelected property in your custom UIButton class like the following :

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        updateState(state: isSelected)
    }
}

func updateState(state: Bool) {

    if state == false {
                self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        print("false")
    } else if state == true {
                self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        print("true")
    }
}
```